# How to make IntelliJ IDEA show vcs label decorator in project tree like Eclipse?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can IntelliJ IDEA show vcs label decorator in project tree (e.g it can show the file status/dirty_flag/last_modify_author/commit_date in vcs like git or svn), just like Eclipse below ?

[image]

IntelliJ has its own [File Status in Views](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html) which is not enough for me.

Comment: No, there is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @yole any plugins to support this?

Answer (score 0):

try to install the plugin VCSLabel